# Angular: Unable to set ngx-bootstrap timepicker with standalone input

Tags: angular, forms, timepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using [this timepicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/timepicker?tab=overview) of **ngx-bootstrap** library.

```html
<ng-template #quantityTimeAdvancedPicker>
  <timepicker
  [showMeridian]="false"
  [showSeconds]="true"
  [minuteStep]="1"
  [secondsStep]="1"
  [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
  [ngModel]="
    data.quantity | secondsInputsToDate
  "
  ></timepicker>
</ng-template>
<input
  class="form-control text-center"
  type="text"
  [popover]="quantityTimeAdvancedPicker"
  [outsideClick]="true"
  placement="bottom"
  [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
  [ngModel]="
    data.quantity
    | secondsInputsToDate
    | date : 'HH:mm:ss'
  "
 (ngModelChange)="setDirty(true)"
/>
```

This is the `SecondsInputsToDatePipe` pipe.

```js
transform(seconds: number): Date {
  const date = moment(
    seconds * 1000 + new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000
    ).toDate();

  return date;
}
```

[image: Timepicker input form]

Everything works ok, but **the timepicker doesn't update the input value**, so I cannot set a new value for quantity. I think it has to be related with the `[ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"` because if I use another component [like ngx-mask](https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask) everything works well, here it is this approach:

```html
<input
  [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
  [ngModel]="data.quantity | secondsToHms"
  (ngModelChange)="
  data.quantity = $event; setDirty(true)"
  type="text"
  class="form-control text-center"
  placeholder="00:00:00"
  mask="00:m0:s0"
/>
```

And the `SecondsToHmsPipe` pipe:

```js
transform(seconds: number): string {
  const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60); //minutes
  const secs = seconds % 60; //seconds
  const hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60); //hours
  const mins = minutes % 60; //minutes

  return (
    '' +
    (hours < 10 ? hours.toString().padStart(2, '0') : hours.toString()) +
    mins.toString().padStart(2, '0') +
    secs.toString().padStart(2, '0')
  );
}
```